# Django overriding filter() without change existing code logic

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-models

I have a table in production that is integrated everywhere in the system, now I need to add a new column in the table with a default value, but don't want to change all the existing logic, what is the best way to do that?

```
class People(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      class = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

in the system, we have this kind of query everywhere

```
People.objects.filter(gender='male')

People.objects.filter(gender='female', class="3rd")
...
```

Now we need to add a new field:

```
class People(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      class = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      graduated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Assume that all the existing data should have `graduated` is False, so all the existing logic should work if we can add `graduated=False` on every query, but is there any way we can do so we don't need to change any of the existing code but they will assume `graduated=False`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make a manager such that `.objects` will only retain `People` with `graduated=False`:

```
class PeopleManager(models.Manager):
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(graduated=False)

class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    graduated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    objects = PeopleManager()
    all = models.Manager()
```

You can use `People.all.all()` to retrieve all `People`, and `People.objects.all()` to retrieve all `People` that did not graduate.

That being said, I do not recommend this: often `People.objects.all()` gives the impression that one will retrieve *all* `People`. As the *Zen of Python* says: "*explicit over implicit*": it is better that the code explains and hints what it is doing, not move filtering somewhere hidden in a manager.